# What is the best cross platform keyboard based web browser?

Tags: keyboard, browser, web

What is the best cross platform keyboard based web browser? I have tried Conkerer only so far, but would like to try others if there are any.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you like vim, you can use an extension for your current browser. All such extensions aim to bring vim-like keyboard browsing to a particular browser, although the implementation of each differs considerably.

## Chrome

- [Vimium](http://vimium.github.com/)
- [Vrome](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAB&url=https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vrome/godjoomfiimiddapohpmfklhgmbfffjj&ei=PYObUcv8J8LQOaqjgIAP&usg=AFQjCNFawpEYD-Hrs52FGIwmANTh7qf0HA&bvm=bv.46751780,d.ZWU)
- [Keyconfig](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/empty-title/okneonigbfnolfkmfgjmaeniipdjkgkl?hl=en)

## Firefox

- [Pentadactyl](http://5digits.org/pentadactyl/)
- [Vimperator](http://vimperator.org/)
- [VimFx](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/vimfx/)

## Opera

- [VimOperate](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/vimoperate/?display=en)

## Safari

- [Vimari](https://github.com/guyht/vimari)

Comment: +1 for Vimperator. Not tried Vimium..

Comment: +1 for extensions for existing browsers instead of a new browser.

Comment: The vimperator nightly builds are working nicely with the Firefox beta